# Gitlab CI Trigger pipeline by workflow rules

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My pipeline keeps getting skipped, even though my branch is develop. Any ideas? Syntax seems correct.

I'm also getting the error when running manually "Pipeline cannot be ran. Pipeline filtered out by rules"

```
  # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
stages:          
  - validate
  - build


# Variables set in the GitLab UI are not passed down to service containers. 
# To set them, assign them to variables in the UI, then re-assign them in your .gitlab-ci.yml
variables:
  COMMIT_BRANCH: ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
  
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
      when: always
      

    



validate-job:
  stage: validate
  script:
  - echo "Validated"


build-job:
  stage: build
  ##some job actions
  script: 
  - echo "t"
  # rules:
    # - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /develop\/.*$/
      # when: always
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is [the bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/425136) which prevents your pipeline to run.

To make it work you should use `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` variable directly in the workflow rules:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
      when: always
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like having same name as gitlab variable name `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` causing this problem.

Perhaps you should be able to run the pipeline successfully by having a `different global variable name` as mentioned in [In servies container](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#in-service-containers)

```
variables:
  COMMIT_BRANCH: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

This should allow the pipeline to run when it is triggered in branch `develop`.

However, it is not clear why having same name as gitlab variable name does not work.

Comment: I've tried this, and I've updated my post with the suggested configuration. My pipeline is still being skipped.

Comment: You have changed the variable name in workflow as well, which is wrong, you should keep using $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH in the workflow rule. It triggered for me.